# How can I create a sink from a list of operations

Tags: akka-stream

I want to create a sink in akka streams which is made up of many operations. 
e.g map, filter, fold and then sink. 
The best I can do at the moment is the following. 
I don't like it because I have to specify broadcast even though I am only letting a single value through.
Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

```
def kafkaSink(): Sink[PartialBatchProcessedResult, NotUsed] = {
    Sink.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[PartialBatchProcessedResult](1))
    broadcast.out(0)
    .fold(new BatchPublishingResponseCollator()) { (c, e) => c.consume(e) }
    .map(_.build())
    .map(a =>
      FunctionalTesterResults(sampleProjectorConfig, 0, a)) ~> Sink.foreach(new KafkaTestResultsReporter().report)
  SinkShape(broadcast.in)
})
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One key point to remember with `akka-stream` is that any number of `Flow` values plus a `Sink` value is still a Sink.

A couple of examples demonstrating this property:

```
val intSink : Sink[Int, _] = Sink.head[Int]

val anotherSink : Sink[Int, _] = 
  Flow[Int].filter(_ > 0)
           .to(intSink)

val oneMoreSink : Sink[Int, _] = 
  Flow[Int].filter(_ > 0)
           .map(_ + 4)
           .to(intSink)
```

Therefore, you can implement the `map` and `filter` as Flows.  The `fold` that you are asking about can be implemented with `Sink.fold`.